# Stopping time and its probability showing $\mathbb{P}(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}_{0} : \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k} > a) \leq e^{-\lambda a}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, problem-solving, stopping-times

The problem is related (or based on) Wald's Equation, but I am struggling finishing the proof.

> We have $(V_{k})_{k \in  \mathbb{N}}$  i.i.d. random Variables on the Probability-space $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P})$ with $\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda V_{1}}] \leq 1$ for $\lambda > 0$ and $(F_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ being the standard filtration.

Now there are two parts of the exercise:

> (a) For $a>0$ show that $\tau := \inf\{n \in \mathbb{N} | \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k} > a\}$ is a stopping time
>
> (b) Show that: $\mathbb{P}(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}_{0} : \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k} > a) \leq e^{-\lambda a}$

*Proof*

**(a)**
I need to show that $\{\tau \leq n \} \in F_{n}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ . First of all I focus on the sum and rewrite it as:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k} > a \iff \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}V_{k}1_{\{n> k-1 \}} > a$$
since $\{n> k-1 \}$ only depends on $\{V_{1},..,V_{k-1}\}$ at most. It follows: $\{V_{1},..,V_{k-1}\} \in F_{k-1} \subset F_{n}$ . But I don't know how to formalize the conclusion and properly write it down?
$$\{\tau \leq n \} = \{\inf\{n \in \mathbb{N} | \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k} > a\} \leq n \} = \{\inf\{n \in \mathbb{N} | \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}V_{k}1_{\{n> k-1 \}} > a\} \leq n \} \in F_{n}$$

**(b)**
There exists $n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ and set $S_{n} := \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}$ such that using the Markov Inequality:
$$\mathbb{P}( S_{n} > a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[S_{n}]}{a}$$
So now I need to show that $\mathbb{E}[S_{n}] \leq e^{\lambda}$. Analog to the proof of Walds Equation I derive:
$$\mathbb{E}[S_{n}] \leq \mathbb{E}[V_{1}] \mathbb{E}[\tau]$$

This is what I came up with but at this point I am stuck. $\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda V_{1}}] \leq 1$ looks like the moment generating function but I don't know if I can follow $\mathbb{E}[V_{1}] \leq 1$ from that since I don't have a density function given.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding (a) I finished the proof as follows:

Set the event $\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}V_{k} > a \} := A \in F_{k}$ since we only need knowledge of $k$ Steps. Then $\{\tau \leq n \} = A \cap \{\tau \leq k-1 \}^{c} \in F_{k} \subset F_{n} $ since both parts are in $F_{k}$ while $\{\tau \leq k-1 \}^{c} = \{\tau \geq k\} = \{\tau > k-1\}$ coming from the indicator $1_{\{n> k-1 \}}$ which I am allowed to pull out of the conditioning. I hope think that should work. I still would be very thankful for any help on **(b)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer to **(b)** in the original question. Foolishly I didn't consider all the data from the original question which I hereby add:

in a previous problem I showed $X_{n} := \prod_{k=1}^{n}e^{\lambda V_{k}}$ being a supermartingale. And it was given that $X_{0} := 1$

$$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{k=1}^{n} V_{k} > a) = \mathbb{P}(X_{\tau} > e^{\lambda a}) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_{\tau}]}{e^{\lambda a}} \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_{0}]}{e^{\lambda a}} = \frac{1}{e^{\lambda a}}$$

I am using the Markov Inequality and optimal stopping theorem, which I also described previously in my comments. There have been computational mistakes in my comments which prevented me finding the solution on an otherwise correct idea.

Comment: One minor correction: $\mathbb{P}(\sum_{k=1}^{n} V_{k} > a) \le \mathbb{P}(X_{\tau} \ge e^{\lambda a})$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has nothing to do with Wald's equation, but rather with optional stopping. For $N\ge 1$, denote $\tau_N = \tau\wedge N$. Then,
$$
e^{\lambda a}\cdot \mathbb{P}(\tau_N<N)\le \mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda S_{\tau_N}}] \leq 1
$$
Now let $N\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your Input and bringing me onto optimal stopping. I think using optimal stopping theorem [(this Def)][1] I can progress: In a previous task we defined $X_{n} := \prod_{k=1}^{n}e^{\lambda V_{k}}$ and showed that this is a supermartingale. This is also $X_{n} = e^{\lambda S_{n}}$. Now my idea is to use the optimal stopping theorem. Using Wikipedias Def. **(a)** is shown above. **(b)** also true since $X_{n}$ is a supermartingale. It is intuitive but is this enough justification?   [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem

Comment: For **(c)** I use your answer showing that $|X_{N \land \tau}|\leq c$ and allowing me to use $\mathbb{E}[X_{\tau}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{0}]$

Starting out: $\mathbb{P}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k} > a) \leq \mathbb{P}(X_{\tau} > e^{a}) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_{\tau}]}{e^{a}} \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_{0}]}{e^{a}} \leq \frac{e^{\lambda}}{e^{a}} = e^{-a\lambda}$

If I am not mistaken this should be the case as: $\mathbb{E}[X_{0}] = e^{\lambda}\mathbb{E}[\prod_{k=1}^{0}e^{V_{k}}]e^{\lambda}= e^{\lambda}\mathbb{E}[e^{0}]$ Will this work out?

Comment: What is c)? It's not in your post.

Comment: (a) (b) (c) in this answer are from the prerequires from the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem